# Docker-compose command not working on Windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-10, docker-for-windows

I have Docker for Windows 10 and always and it has worked well.

But today not working anymore. If I give a docker-compose up nothing happens, it just goes to the bottom line.
The commands docker-compose up, docker-compose build, docker-compose -v, nothing happens, no error, just goes to the bottom line.

I uninstalled docker and I disabled Hyper-V, I installed all again and it did not work.

One example of the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  data:
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=db
```

Thanks!

Update:
I installed a version previous and I have the same thing.

Update2:
I downgrade to version 17.12.0-ce-win47 and it's works. More people with the same problem here.
https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2699

```
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 18.06.0-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: d64c661f1d51c48782c9cec8fda7604785f93587
runc version: 69663f0bd4b60df09991c08812a60108003fa340
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.9.93-linuxkit-aufs
Operating System: Docker for Windows
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 1.934GiB
Name: linuxkit-00155d0f1009
ID: FTO7:ABFI:2B7X:5KYO:R4YA:R4QI:62LR:GYSA:QOWS:A4DO:RKOK:45WR
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 22
 Goroutines: 46
 System Time: 2018-10-10T00:45:47.3809481Z
 EventsListeners: 1
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Comment: Could you paste your `docker info` output?

Comment: @lagom, I downgrade to version 17.12.0-ce-win47 and it's works.

Answer (score 0):

For other people with the same problem, I downgrade to version 17.12.0-ce-win47 and it works. 
Not is necessarily a solution, but I can work.